# traducir codigo pdo a mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

¿como puedo traducir este codigo de pdo a mysqli?Se trata de un codigo para obtener los valores de un campo tipo enum de una base de datos y mostrarlos.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    function get_enum_values($gbd, $table, $field){

        $sth=$gbd->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM {$table} WHERE Field='{$field}'");
        $sth->execute();
        preg_match("/^enum\(\'(.*)\'\)$/",$sth->fetch()["Type"],$matches);
        $enum=explode("','",$matches[1]);
        return $enum;
    }        
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=pruebaSelect;host=localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '1*Ouroverde';
    $gbd = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    print_r(get_enum_values($gbd, "Empleado", "estado"));
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Traducir ?? Es cosa de buscar como se hace una conexion mysqli. Es muy similar la verdad. Y por que el cambio ? no funciona ?

Comment: En teoría, solo deberías cambiar `new PDO()` por [`new mysqli()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.construct.php), [vincular variables de resultados](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) y analizar la variable correspondiente a `Type` después de [`$sth->fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)